# Is powersemantics.com spam?

Tags: discussion, answers, spam

I found a new [wiki answer posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467724/alternatives-to-object-oriented-programming/61683746#61683746) ([image for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEGvd.png)) which looked really spammy to me on the first sight. Upon checking the user's history I identified that they have used their answers to promote their own site/product multiple times ([linked in 24](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A13028619+url%3Apowersemantics.com&mixed=0) of their 40 answers, and not linked in any other posts on Stack Exchange).

I flagged it for a moderator's attention with the following message:

> I am flagging this as possible spam. A lot of this user's answers talk about their site and it looks like their main purpose is to promote that product. The site looks very dodgy. It has been discussed in SOCVR: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49327004#49327004 Could someone take a look at it and judge if it really is spam and should be removed? Thanks.

The flag was marked as helpful 3 hours later and that community wiki answer got removed, but the other answers were left untouched.

Was I wrong to think that this user is overly self-promoting?

Comment: That site is a lot of fun.

Comment: The substance of your question lies within *The flag was marked as helpful 3 hours later and that community wiki answer got removed, but the other answers were left untouched*. This is a lot like some bugs in the application I'm working on, with pressure and circumstances sometimes dictating that you will fix the symptom and not the cause. That said, three hours is not much, and I would encourage you to flag other symptoms of this problem in the same way you did for your canonical example, as I appear to remember that flags are somehow grouped by occurrences in moderator interfaces.

Comment: That user sounds like some kind of evangelist

Comment: @QBrute it not a crime to be passionate about something. Just don't brag about it in all posts ...

Comment: Interesting website.  It is very reminiscent of a system my ex-boss wrote at a previous company called a "workflow server."   It's basically the Actor Model; you can do the same thing with Akka or something similar, and it will follow all the same rules and top it off with resiliency and scalability.  Good ideas, but nothing particularly new or remarkable to see here.

Comment: Another critique of (the complexities of) OOP is Brian Will's *[Object-Oriented](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM1iUe6IofM) [Programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IRTfhkiAqPw) [is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6VP-2aIcSc) [Bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iyB0_qPvWk)* (four parts). E.g. *"Object-oriented programming doesn't fit* ***any*** *problem."* (00 min 32 secs in the first). Listen to it with an open mind.

Comment: Note: The author of the posts under discussion has provided some feedback [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61645311/10871073), presumably prompted by the canned 'spam warning' comment I put on one of their posts.

Comment: Would protocol dictate that they be given a link to here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I caught the flag, reviewed the answer, and agreed with you that it was unmistakably spammy. That "I will change the world" opening line was clear spam, if not outright crackpot-ism. The very next paragraphs looked like something out of a first-year marketing student's project: "My collaborative architecture…is the ultimate form of source code…" I even nuked the answer as spam initially.

But when I went through the poster's recent answer history (I read their last 16 answers prior to this one), I found that I could not justifiably consider any of them to be spam. Sure, they post the same link a lot, and they're clearly affiliated with this link. They *might* even be a crank. (Remember that moderators don't judge technical accuracy.) But neither of those criteria are enough for moderators to nuke answers as spam or accounts as spammers. The answers were ostensibly relevant to the questions that were asked, and whenever the link was provided, there was a clear (almost always unmistakable) disclaimer offered. That pretty much meets [the guidelines in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

The only thing that troubled me was the fact that nearly all of their answers contained this link. The above-linked Help Center article *does* say (emphasis original, and appropriate here):

> Post good, relevant answers, and if some (**but not all**) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay.

This user was, indeed, veering dangerously close to all of their answers containing links to a website/product that they are obviously affiliated with. But not quite all. The user *has* posted answers that don't contain the link to this website, and don't even appear to be about this same topic. (As mentioned above, I reached that judgment by looking at their most recent 17 answers. They had posted a total of 43 answers at the time of investigation. I didn't go through them all.)

The picture that started to emerge for me was of a user who, while they had a vested interest in a particular topic and did like to link their own website, was also just passionate about a subject and tended to share their knowledge on the subjects they felt they knew best. That's…a lot like what we *want* people to do, and not really spam.

With this in mind, I went back to reconsider the originally-flagged answer, ultimately disputing my own spam flag and just deleting it so as not to apply a spam penalty to the associated account.

---

**In summary, what I saw was:**

- **A clearly inappropriate, spammy answer, which I removed.**
- **A dedicated, albeit dogmatic, user who had a pretty laser-like focus on one topic.**
- **A user having an affiliation with a particular product/service, who tended to promote that product, but almost always with adequate disclaimers and only when it was arguably relevant to the question being asked.**

**It's potentially concerning behavior, and definitely something to keep an eye on, but not something that I considered to be requiring of broader action at this time.**

I'm open to reconsidering this, of course. Moderation is about making judgments. The above describes the one which I made at the time. If anyone thinks I missed some evidence that should have been considered, please raise another flag.

Comment: Not to say that you're wrong, but this _is_ remarkably similar behavior to [the original case](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/145897) that first got the issue of "how much self-promotion is too much" hashed out and ruled on for SO.

Comment: Where is the adequate disclaimer in (randomly chosen example) [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60675393/674039)? It looks like the hyperlink is just dumped in there for the purposes of SEO to me.

Comment: Out of 24 answers containing the link there are 7 that have no (or very unclear) disclosure.

Comment: Did you have time to check the [about](http://www.powersemantics.com/about.html) page? I was personally fond of the [licensing](http://www.powersemantics.com/licensing.html).

Comment: I was (during the linked discussion in SOCVR), and still am, pretty much 50:50 on this one! Where is the line between acceptable self-promotion and **over**-promotion? Last week, what finally tipped me into the "not spam" camp were the two kittens (Elvira and Pugsley) mentioned on the [contacts page](http://www.powersemantics.com/contact.html). But then I drifted the other way a  bit. Dilemma - error 717.

Comment: I don't agree that there isn't a problem here. I've reread the [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), and while it repeats the "some (but not all)", I do not believe it's meant to be taken literally, for example "all posts but one". I noticed the "If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website..", which I'd say 50% is.